# How to switch workspace by scrolling mouse pointer over ubuntu-dock

Tags: 20.04, gnome, mouse, workspaces

I can't seem to be able to switch workspace by scrolling mouse wheel when the mouse pointer is over the dock for Ubuntu 20.04.

To switch workspace by mouse scrolling over the dock: `org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock.scroll-switch-workspace` is using default value, i.e. `true`. But this setting don't seem to work.

To switch workspace when scrolling on the application icon, `org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock.scroll-action` is using default value, i.e. `'switch-workspace'` This setting works.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the following:

1. By default, `org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock.custom-theme-shrink` default value is `true`. With this setting activated, the dock height shrinks to the height of the buttons in the dock. W/o this setting activated, the height of the dock will expand, exposing dock space above and below the button. When the mouse pointer is positioned at these exposed dock spaces, I would be able to switch workspace using the mouse scroll wheel.
2. Note, there are always exposed dock spaces on the left and right of a button regardless of the setting of `org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock.custom-theme-shrink`. However, they can't be used with the mouse wheel to scroll workspace. I suspect this is a bug of ubuntu-dock that needs to be corrected.

The source code to ubuntu-dock is in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com` and its behaviour controlled by JavaScript. I suspect changes is needed in `docking.js` and/or `dash.js` to allow the switching of workspace by mouse wheel when the mouse pointer is located in the dock spaces between the Favourite App buttons.